# How can I statically compile programs?

Tags: linux, ssh, gcc

I need to statically compile programs, for example: sudo. I need this so I can run them on a compromised system over ssh.

But how would I do this? I know that I can find shared libraries with ldd. And I can compile with "gcc -static". But how do I combine these two things?

Comment: You don't ... you install the required `-dev` packages for your distro, and those come `.a` files for static linking.

Comment: ... and WITH those ... do'h.